# VScode eslint parser error with ‘%=’ token

Tags: jsp, parsing, visual-studio-code, eslint

I use eslint-html-plugin to validate JavaScript inside JSP file
In the JSP file there are some thing like :

```
var ConnNo = <%= PubConstants.ConnectionNo%>;
```

eslint parser cannot handle such syntax, and return the information that "eslint parsing error unexpected token"
could you help me to rectify this problem, I will be grateful if you could help me to enhance my code quality.
[image]

Comment: Try putting that inside `""` and see onces.

Comment: The scripts in JSP files *aren't* just JavaScript, so ESLint won't be able to parse them without help.

Comment: thanks for you comment, yes, if you put that line inside "", it will be ok for eslint parser, but it won't work for browser.

Comment: Did you run that? Does it has any value? Because this should work. Can you do `console.log(ConnNo)` and see if this gets shown in browser console or not

Comment: HaHa, I am a  newbie， thank you for you nice and patient suggestion. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do as Mr. Swati  says helps me solve this problem: Try putting that inside "" and see onces.  Thanks for his answer. I don know how to choose his suggestion as final answer, So I copy his answer and thanks him here. @Swati
I will accept this answer tomorrow.

Comment: Hi it should be `her` not `him` :D